# auto compile MS visual c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I have 2 programs: One written in c++ and compile on MS visual studio 2010; The other written in C# and compile on MS visual studio 2010.

My second program automatically edit one of first projects file (.cpp), I want to know is there any way to auto compile my c++ code on file changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Run a command line build of the C++ project through the C# app. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394036/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-from-a-c-sharp-windows-form-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, call `msbuild`.

E.g.

```
msbuild YourSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

(Or Debug, if that's what you're building for)

Sounds like your tool would be better off written as an msbuild task though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536539/how-to-call-msbuild-from-c-sharp i tried this code but it is not working is there any good article demonstrating this issue?