# creating a batch file in c#

Tags: c#, batch-file, com0com

This is my first time creating a batch. basically i want write commands in the command Promt. so i need batch file so that i can it in c# and does the task.

The commands looks like this:

```
install PortName=COM50-
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

How i can create the batch file and run it using c# code.

Thanks

Details: i am using com0com to create virtual ports, so the main idea is to automate the process, so i can create port without going to command port and write the commands.

Comment: Open notepad, save the command in file with extension `.bat`, then [use that batch file in C# Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394036/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-from-a-c-sharp-windows-form-app)

Comment: See here for how to run a batch file from C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You maybe don't need a batch file :-

```
 Process myprocess = new Process();
 myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WHERE_EVER\bcdedit.exe";
 // I dont know the exact switch, but im sure you would be able to work this out.
 myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"Install PortName=COM50 -set TESTSIGNING OFF";
 myprocess.Start();
```

Comment: ` myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"Install PortName=COM50 -set TESTSIGNING OFF";  ` doest work. when the command prompt starts, how do u execute inside it. basically how to pass the command?

Comment: That's something you would need to check out yourself, I just gave that switch as an example. I dont know what BCDedit is.

Comment: i fixed it.. thanks.. i wrote the command in batch file and run it, it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Write the commands to a file and call [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) with the path to the file.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx) is your best option.

> Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start
>   and stop local system processes.

For example;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\yourfilename.bat");
```