# Running a batch file before tomcat service starts when user manually starts the service in services.msc

Tags: tomcat, service, windows-services, batch-file

I would like to know if there is any way of running an operation (like, calling a batch file) before a service is started using services.msc?

I want my batch file to run before the service (tomcat installed as service) is actually started, when the user manually clicks 'Start' in Services.

I don't know if this is possible or not. 
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I think this may be your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file

Comment: @BullFeathers Thanks, but I was actually aiming not to modify the service itself. Perhaps, if there's an existing batch file that i can configure to call my batch file every time tomcat starts, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **NO**, unless you want to modify Apache's `procrun` (which is written in C language).

Depending on what you wanted to do, you should also check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256612).

One possible way of doing something when a web application is started - on top my mind - would be to write a `javax.Servlet.ServletContextListener` as explained [here](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/listener-in-java/). In
you listener's `contextInitialized()` you would start your BAT file via `Runtime.exec()` as explained [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016).