# running a batch file through c# console app. Commands get ignored

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, console-application, command-prompt

i'm trying to execute a .bat file through a c# console application using code from here:
[Service hangs up at WaitForExit after calling batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file)

Kevin's solution kinda works, but some commands in my .bat file get ignored for some reason, but when i manually execute the .bat file all commands work just fine.

e.g. xcopy command doesn't work while executing .bat from console app, but start command works fine.

Any idea why this happens?

p.s. recently i found that if the program is being launched from command prompt, it works well. How come? Still i need to put it on autorun, so this doesn't solve the problem.

Also, if launched by clicking on exe file, output shows

xcopy folder1 folder2

but if launched from command prompt, output shows

xcopy folder1 folder2

smth/smth.smth copied

....

5 files copied.

And it actually is being copied.

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName                 = target;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError    = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput   = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute          = false;

        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit
            (
                (timeout <= 0)
                ? int.MaxValue : timeout * NO_MILLISECONDS_IN_A_SECOND *
                   NO_SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE
            );

        errorMessage    = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        outputMessage   = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: can you point out which commands get ignored?

Comment: Did you set `WorkingDir` inside your process before running it? If you did not your batch file could not find files defined with partial path...

Comment: Maybe it's a security issue (the spawned process doesn't have write access to some of your files/paths).  An overload of the `Start()` method lets you provide a username/password. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx

Comment: You can get console standard output and error output redirected to you program. Maybe xcopy prints an error that might help.

Comment: Marco, i'm using absolute paths, so that shouldn't be the problem.
Sascha, yes I looked at that, absolutely no errors, output shows that all commands are executed, but they are not.
Chris, no password is used on ANY user, and the programm is run "as administrator" in windows 7.

Comment: Shai, rmdir and xcopy both don't work.

Comment: Put a deliberate error in your batch file, e.g., xxcopy instead of xcopy, and see whether you see the error message or not.

Comment: Yep, i get
Error message: 'xxcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try replace xcopy with cmd /c xcopy and see what happens.

Comment: There are a number of different code fragments in the question you reference.  Could you put the actual code you're using in your question?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're describing, but I think you need to use asynchronous IO.  The code you've given will deadlock if there is more standard output than will fit in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Batch file commands do *not* get ignored when you execute the command processor from a service.  They however easily *fail* and can do so unobserved since you cannot see their output.  Typical reasons for failure are having the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory not set correctly so that relative paths no longer work or trouble caused by the service running with a different user account that doesn't have the same rights as the one you use from the desktop.

Diagnose problems by redirecting output to a file, run cmd.exe /c and use the `>` operator.  Append `2>&1` so that the file contains both regular and error output.  And by using the [%errorlevel% variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920) and [EXIT command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490902) judiciously so you can discover that execution failed by using the Process.ExitCode property.

Comment: Hans, there are absolutely no errors, also paths are absolute. Also please see additions above.

Comment: You broke my crystal ball.  Great, I wasn't planning to go shopping today.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it, English is not my first language.

Comment: As long as you don't tell us *exactly* what commands you use and *exactly* how you know they didn't do the job then I have no good guess left what your problem might be.

Comment: As i mentioned in comments above, i'm using rmdir and xcopy. I can tell they don't work because they kinda don't work i.e. they don't delete or copy anything. although they work if program is being launched from command prompt.

Comment: Great, got that new crystal ball and you broke it *again*.  It couldn't cope with "kinda".  Glowed red of a minute and poof!  Signing off, got some careful recycling to do so I don't spend the whole freaking' week at the shopping mawl.