# Trouble running .cmd file with c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, cmd

For some reason, I can't seem to launch and run a .cmd file with c#.  An example of a line of the cmd file is:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg64.exe" -v verbose -y -i "S:\TEMP\A.ts" -c:v copy -c:a copy -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 2 "S:\TEMP\A_SHORT.ts"
```

I've tried several different ways to launch this file from within C#, such as (where curDirectory is for example "S:\TEMP")

```
Process p = Process.Start(curDirectory + "\\ffmpeg.cmd");
```

I've also tried

```
string path = curDirectory + "\\ffmpeg.cmd";
Process p = Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c " + path);  //I've also tried /k
```

But what happens is the cmd prompt will show up and say "C:\Windows\System32\ffmpeg64.exe" is not recognized ..." even though the file is there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you run the .cmd file in question manually from the command prompt, it completes without error? Have you tried building a `ProcessStartInfo` object?

Comment: I should have mentioned that it runs perfectly fine when I double-click it AND when I run it from cmd.  I have tried the ProcessStartInfo object as such `ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(path)` but it also fails

Comment: are you running C# as admin?

Comment: check this out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file\

Comment: Tried running c# as admin, no go.  I also tried a few more permutations of starting a process, some running cmd.exe with arguments `"/c " + path`, some directly calling the .cmd file.  Everything keeps giving me the same "not recognized" message.  I would really rather not have to read in the .cmd file, parse it, then run the arguments directly through ffmpeg64.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Okay, I moved ffmpeg64 to C:\ and correspondingly changed the path in my .cmd file.  Now it works.  Why can't I run ffmpeg64.exe from C:\Windows\System32\ in C# but I can anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If your system is running the Windows 6.1 kernel or later, System32 is actually comprised of other directories based on the application you're running (depending on whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit application).

I assume that `ffmpeg64.exe` is a 64-bit application, and when you execute the .cmd file manually, it should default to a 64-bit command prompt - Also ensure that your application is targeting "x64" or "Any CPU". Alternatively, you could place a 32-bit version of ffmpeg in the WoW64 directory.

Also, I know you've stated in comments that you don't want to read the .cmd file and modify it, but you could compose your `ProcessStartInfo` with `Environment.SystemDirectory` instead of the hard-coded path.

As a last option, you could place the ffmpeg exe somewhere static (as you stated in the comments, in `c:\` works), or just in your application's working directory.