# Call one batch from another, then start services

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to call a batch on a local machine from another batch. Then I'm trying to start services on a remote computer. Here is my code:

```
call C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\epm_system\bin\start.bat > SS.log
sc \\OtherMachine start "Service1" >> SS.log
sc \\OtherMachine start "Service2" >> SS.log
```

I've already confirmed that I can start the services without starting `start.bat` beforehand. However, when I try to call `start.bat` using the first line of code, it just closes once that completes without running the last two lines.

Comment: Does that mean it doesn't execute the last two lines in the code you've posted above?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Strange.  Does `start.bat` contain an `EXIT` or `GOTO:EOF` command? If it does, you could try changing it to `EXIT /B` http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php

Comment: Can't change the batch. Is there any way to call it in a new window so that it closes and let the first keep running?

Comment: Not if it contains an `EXIT` command.  The `EXIT` command apparently kills the entire batch.  You would have to write a program, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/361121/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey What about using `start /wait` instead of call? It should be effectively the same (in this particular instance) but not kill the caller as it runs in separate cmd instance

Answer (score 1):

you can call cmd.exe within your first batch, that will not close it if the second batch contains exit.
example:
call.cmd

```
cmd /c "c:\temp\test.cmd"
echo end of first batch
```

test.cmd

```
@echo off
echo test 
exit
```

result :

```
C:\temp>call.cmd
test
end of first batch
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: @DrewRush please provide more details : what's the error ? What's inside start.bat ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I bill by the hour so I can only spend so much time on any given problem. I've found another approach that works. Thanks for your time and interest, I'm very grateful.