# How to run VBS script from C# code

Tags: c#

All what I am trying to do is to be able to run VBS script from code behind but I am getting this error: “The system cannot find the file specified”.  I know the path name and I only need to execute that .vbs script but it is giving me hard time and I am not able to figure out.  Please help.  Thanks
here is my code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cscript  //B //Nologo \\loc1\test\myfolder\test1.vbs");
```

i have updated the code as shown below but i am getting a security warning asking me if i want to open it. Is there a way to not get those kind of warning and just run script without any warnings?
here is the updated code:

```
  Process proc = null;
        try
        {
            string targetDir = string.Format(@"\\loc1\test\myfolder");//this is where mybatch.bat lies
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "test1.vbs";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");//this is argument
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code working fine for me, **I think the error was in your File Path**,

Better *Confirm the File Path you given is valid or Not*..

You can run that file like below also..

```
Process scriptProc = new Process();
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript"; 
scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments ="//B //Nologo \\loc1\test\myfolder\test1.vbs";
scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
scriptProc.Start();
scriptProc.WaitForExit();
scriptProc.Close();
```

But *check your File Path* you given..

Comment: i think this worked fine with no problem but if you could tell me if i want to run vbs script that is located on another server how would i do this?  i am assuming i have to provide user name and password but don't name how to modify this code?  thanks

Comment: @moe - Newer versions of Windows require you to authorize running script files like this.  Update your question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters have to be included separately.  There is an arguments field you use to pass arguments to the process.

You can use this as a guide for executing [programs with command line from an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file/361121).

Comment: kevin i just updated my initial post please see above.  i am getting a warnings before i am able to execute the script.  thanks

Comment: For kicks, try moving the vbs script to a local drive, and see if that gets rid of it.